# Add styles with wp_add_inline_style only if modifications exist wp_add_inline_style

Tags: customization

I am building a theme that lets users make modifications to their WP site through Customizer. I use wp_add_inline_style to output css changes based on user input. Right now inline styles are added to the head regardless of whether there are modifications to the theme or not. I would like to be able to check whether modifications exist and only THEN to add inline styles to the head.

Here is code example:

```
<?php

function mytheme_custom_styles() {

//typography setting for hero text
$onepageps_site_title_font = get_theme_mod('sitetitle_typography');
$onepageps_site_title_weight = get_theme_mod('sitetitle_weight');
$onepageps_site_title_style = get_theme_mod('sitetitle_style');

$custom_css = "
.site-title {
        font-family:{$onepageps_site_title_font};
        font-weight:{$onepageps_site_title_weight};
        font-style:{$onepageps_site_title_style};
    }
";

wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-specific', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_styles' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function mytheme_custom_styles() {

    // Initialize the variable
    $custom_css = '';

    // check if it's empty
    if( '' != get_theme_mod('sitetitle_typography') ) {
        $custom_css .= 'font-family: ' . get_theme_mod('sitetitle_typography') . ';';
    }
    // check if it's empty
    if( '' != get_theme_mod('sitetitle_weight') ) {
        $custom_css .= 'font-weight: ' . get_theme_mod('sitetitle_weight') . ';';
    }
    // check if it's empty
    if( '' != get_theme_mod('sitetitle_style' ) ) {
        $custom_css .= 'font-style: ' . get_theme_mod('sitetitle_style') . ';'; 
    }
    // if variable $custom_css has changed, then add the changes and execute wp_add_inline_style
    if( '' != $custom_css ) {
        $custom_css = '.site-title {' . $custom_css . '}';
        wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-specific', $custom_css );
    }

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_styles' );
```

Note that "theme-specific" css stylesheet, had to be enqueued at some point along your theme's code.

Let me know if it helps you!

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I have other elements that I need styled dynamically, e.g h2, links, buttons etc. 
Is there a way to output all of the inline css into one chunk instead of breaking it into separate blocks?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you to initialize two or three different variables i.e. `$sitetitle_css` `$h2_css` `$link_css`, and then populate them conditionally, according the different `get_them_mod` evaluations. Finally, you just need to put all the variables into one.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured it out yesterday as well. Everything is working like a charm :-) Thanks for your help!